# iOS 7: swipe between table views with navigation bar at the bottom

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uitableview, uiswipegesturerecognizer

I am new to IOS, and developing an app that has navigation bar at the bottom to switch between views by tapping the tabs in the bar. Now, I would like to add in swipe gesture so users can also change table views by swiping.

However, navigation controller and table view controller are two different classes. I tried all combinations using the storyboard interface, but none of them allow me to swipe between views with updated tabs in the navigation bar. I couldn't find any tutorials/answers to this problem online as well.

Suggestions?

Comment: Not sure i fully understand... add a swipe gesture, which then manually calls the segue / or selects the index of the tab bar etc.

Comment: It is difficult to understand you. Navigation bar (at the top) has buttons. Tab Bar (at the bottom) has tabs. Are you sure your problem description is correct?

Answer (score 0):

I do not think it is possible to do this only with storyboard. You can try following code, but probably you should read some docs also.
in ViewDidLoad:

```
UISwipeGestureRecognizer *swipeRecognizerLeft = [ [ UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc ] initWithTarget:self action:@selector( slideLeft ) ];
[ swipeRecognizerLeft setDirection:( UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft ) ];
[ self.view addGestureRecognizer:swipeRecognizerLeft ];
```

Additional method:

```
- (void) slideLeft
{
    self.tabBarController.selectedIndex++;
}
```